# Деепричастие "перелезши"

Tags: словообразование

Можно ли образовать деепричастие "перелезши"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Перелезть — перелезши.***

Суффикс ШИ используется для образования деепричастий совершенного вида от основ на согласную, **поэтому это разрешенная форма.** В то же время в современном языке такое деепричастие используются редко.

Примеры:

....и пенившейся; наконец , по пешеходному мосту, обратно на левый берег и, **перелезши через ограду, на одну из тех каменистых отмелей, которых вообще много на Изаре. [Алексей Макушинский.** Город в долине (2012)]

Райский последовал, хотя не так проворно, его примеру, и оба тем же путем, через садик, и **перелезши опять через забор,** вышли на улицу. [И. А. Гончаров. Обрыв (1869)]

Answer (score -1):

Можно. Образовано от глагола "перелезть".

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/перелезши](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%88%D0%B8)

Answer (score -1):

Думаю можно - и без оговорок на стиль.
Я не вижу причин записывать "перелезши" в устарешие. Дело в том, что есть небольшая группа глаголов, от которых деепричастия совершенного вида по общим современным правилам не образуются - по разным причинам, в основном - фонетическим.

Например:

> Суффикс -ши используется при образовании деепричастий от основ на
>   согласный (вынести — вынесши, потрясти — потрясши). Некоторые глаголы
>   совершенного вида образуют наряду с деепричастиями на -в, -вши, -ши
>   также деепричастия с суффиксом -а (-я) от основы настоящего времени:
>   увидя, наклоня, подметя, принеся.

**Перелезши** вполне вписывается в этот ряд. Аванесов, правда, дает к нему пометку *неуп.*, но в его обозначениях это следует толковать как "малоупотребительно", неупотребительные вовсе формы в его словаре не представлены. В этом кстати, отличие от вики-словаря, там, следуя подходу Зализняка, дают все грамматически возможные формы - без оценки их реальной употребимости.

https://povto.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskie/avanesov/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0376.htm